# Mininet script sending traffic from virtual machine's IP instead of host machines'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, network-programming, mininet

In a python3/mininet script I have a tested, valid dictionary of host machines and their IP addresses.
For each of the keys - by iterating `dictOfAllHostsAndIPs.keys()` - I execute a script on each emulated host's terminal

```
for host in dictOfAllHostsAndIPs.keys():
    host.cmd(os.system( "python3 ./traffic_generator.py %s" % <my_args>))
```

This script that sends random packet to IP addresses randomly picked from the list of IPs on the emulated network -- it generates traffic quite randomly using echo to pipe some data to netcat that hands it out on a port that is normally not in use :

`os.system("echo -n '%s'" % data_string + " | nc %s 1299" % str(random_ip))`)

My issue is that when I launch packet sniffers (mostly **tshark**) on each and every switch on the network, in the resulting logs in the TCP frames data I see on the first line that they all come from my VM's IP (192.168.119.133) instead of the host machines (10.0.0.XX), and in the ethernet/source line I always get the MAC address of the VM itself instead of the virtual machines.

```
# frame# /time(epoch) /     source ip → dest ip    /   ports: src → dest
>       8 0.063202633 192.168.119.133 → 10.0.0.1     TCP 74 40370 → 1299

> Ethernet II, Src: VMware_34:8e:de (00:0c:29:34:8e:de), Dst:
> VMware_fa:1a:ac (00:50:56:fa:1a:ac)
>     Destination: VMware_fa:1a:ac (00:50:56:fa:1a:ac)
>         Address: VMware_fa:1a:ac (00:50:56:fa:1a:ac)
>         
>     Source: VMware_34:8e:de (00:0c:29:34:8e:de)
>         Address: VMware_34:8e:de (00:0c:29:34:8e:de)
```

The only thing that changes in the source section of the frames I see in my logs is the port from which the VM is sending the packets, which is always between 35000 and 49999 (or maybe 50k and something). (see first line of the log above, `ports: src`)

I initially assumed that each one of the ports being used was dedicated to sending traffic from the different emulated host machine, but they're way too many and they don't stay the same, so this is clearly not the case.

Not having realized this right away (everything else looked and still looks okay: packet destination and every other parameter I need to check for my research project), I have then implemented a modular, threaded refactoring of my code. So now I look at the logs of the different versions of my program and they all have the same issue, no matter how I run the traffic generation script (older versions) or the instantiation of trafficGenerator objects (newer versions), so this issue is not dependent on this aspect of my scripts' structure.

I checked on and fiddled with my calls many times, quadruple-checked the lists (then dicts, then lists again) that I iterate through in order to have the individual machines run the traffic generation code with `for hosts in list(net.get(hosts)): host.cmd(<action>)`
The latest version goes like this:

```
    listOfTGs = []
### Create a list of threads for parallel execution
    listOfThreads = []
    for host in dictOfAllHostsAndIPs.keys():
###     Create a trafficGenerator object on the mininet machine, then call commands on host
        listOfTGs.append(tg.TrafficGenerator(durationFromArgument, host.name, callable_ips_list, net))
    for tg_instance in listOfTGs:
        listOfThreads.append(tg_instance.threadedExecution())
    print(listOfThreads)
    for th in listOfThreads:
        th.start()
```

I can confirm (after maaaany careful print-based debugging hours) that the action of generating traffic, as all other actions, is executed once for each emulated host machine, in parallel, with the correct identity for each host visible in the stdout. And still, the IP that I get when sniffing the packets is the one of the VM itself instead of the one of the host machine that *should* appear. And in papers from other researchers I see that they have it correctly in their sniffing analysis, so this is not just "something that mininet does this way" (I looked into it in order to be sure).

TL;DR: my problem is that the source of the packets being sent around is the VM itself on which I launch the mininet emulations, and not the host machines being emulated in whose name I call the traffic generation processes.

Comment: Are you doing anything special before that `os.system` call to switch network namespaces or tell mininet "run these commands from this fake host"?

Comment: Yes @LiamKelly, the full call at the moment is done on the switch object. The call is 

```for switch in net.switches:
        switch.cmd(tr.trafficRecorder(switch.name, durationFromArgument))```

Comment: Can you point to the API document for the `cmd` method? I see reference to a `sendCmd` method [here](http://mininet.org/api/classmininet_1_1node_1_1Switch.html#abadff1b279f6fe05529ef47e82692195), but not a `cmd`. Basically it looks like you are either sending the command in the root net namespace (IE: your normal VM) or you have a NAT rule for traffic leavinging the Mininets Net Namespaces (pretty common for these types of tools).

Comment: there's an entry in the mininet python API, it's defined as mininet.node.Node.cmd so I really thought it must be callable upon a specific node
http://mininet.org/api/classmininet_1_1node_1_1Node.html#a6e1338af3c4a0348963a257ac548153b
AFAIK the main difference is cmd waits for output, sendCmd does not wait for the command to be complete

Comment: Actually I'm sure it is called upon a defined namespace, since it's one of the ways I used to get all the host machines' IP addresses on the network and in that case it works alright, it's verified. Maybe I'm not supposed to make calls to the bash terminal of the switches but I don't see why that would cause the fact that they see the traffic as coming from the VM's IP. I really think the bug is in the way I create traffic.

Comment: Assuming you have the netns names you can test your theory, I'll add to my answer.

Comment: Unluckily my work planning has abruptly taken me away from this project for a week or so. I'll let you know as soon as I can the result of this test.
PS let me know if you want me to share the whole project with you (~5 python modules and a bash script, all between 10 and 100 lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see what is going on in the source, but i have not run the framework to confirm it.

It looks like mininet inatalls a [NAT rule](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/57294d013e780cccc6b4b9af151906b382c4d8a7/mininet/nodelib.py#L133) for every node:

```
    self.cmd( 'iptables -I FORWARD',
              '-i', self.localIntf, '-d', self.subnet, '-j DROP' )
    self.cmd( 'iptables -A FORWARD',
              '-i', self.localIntf, '-s', self.subnet, '-j ACCEPT' )
    self.cmd( 'iptables -A FORWARD',
              '-o', self.localIntf, '-d', self.subnet, '-j ACCEPT' )
    self.cmd( 'iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING',
              '-s', self.subnet, "'!'", '-d', self.subnet,
              '-j MASQUERADE' )

     # Instruct the kernel to perform forwarding
    self.cmd( 'sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1' )
```

So basically if traffic has a destination outside of the node's subnet a NAT (MASQUAERADE) rule is applied. Assuming this is also occurring in the root net namespace, then all outbound traffic is NAT'd (IE: takes the IP of the last hop).

#### How to prove this

1. Set up your mininet network.
2. Look at your root namespace NAT rules  with `iptables -t nat -L`. If you see a MASQUERADE entry then that is the NAT rule that you are having issues with
3. You should be able to see the individual namespaces with `ip netns list`. I believe they should just be labeled as [numbers](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/57294d013e780cccc6b4b9af151906b382c4d8a7/examples/cluster.py#L406).
4. For every namespace in that list enter `ip netns exec $NETNSNAME iptables -t nat -L` . Observe any more NAT rules.

#### How to test if mininet is executing commands in the root Net Namespace

Aside from a NAT rule, the other likely source of the issue would be that mininet is not executing the command from the node's net namespace but the root namespace. This should be easy to test as well.

1. Set up your mininet network.
2. You should be able to see the individual namespaces with `ip netns list`. I believe they should just be labeled as [numbers](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/57294d013e780cccc6b4b9af151906b382c4d8a7/examples/cluster.py#L406).
3. For every namespace in that list enter `ip netns exec $NETNSNAME ip addr show`. Observe the IP addresses.
4. For the namespace that corresponds with the node you wish to send traffic from, run the following: `ip netns exec $NETNSNAME bash -c "echo -n $DATASTRING | nc $RANDOMIP 1299"` where you have the BASH variables for DATASTRING and RANDOMIP already set.
5. Observe traffic as you did prior.

If the traffic you observe still has the VM's src IP then it is likely a NAT rule causing the issue. If it has the node's IP then mininet is not executing the command in the correct namespace.